# Keyboard Shortcut in "The Social Network"

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

In the movie "The Social Network" featuring Jesse Eisenberg as Mark Zuckerberg, there's a scene where Zuckerberg is in a computer lab (presumably working) at a computer when one of his friends approaches him.  He gets an idea for his site and gathers his things to leave.  Before he exits the computer lab, however, the camera (seemingly very purposefully) transitions to a close-up shot of the keyboard at the computer and shows him hitting (what appears to be) the `Esc` key twice in succession.  It's hard to discern if he's holding any other keys as he does so, but even still, the intent seems pretty clear; he's done using the computer.  Maybe he's locking it or shutting it down.  Perhaps he's just exiting out of a program.

I can't imagine what keyboard shortcut entails hitting `Esc` twice in a row.  As this movie takes place in the early 2000s, it's possible this is something specific to an older version of Windows or even an old version of a desktop application.

I'm curious as to what might this keyboard shortcut be - assuming it's a legitimate keyboard shortcut at all!  It's possible that this is just some dramatic movie artsiness designed to convey how much of a hurry he is to get back to his dorm and implement the idea.  Maybe the fact that he hit the key twice is unimportant.

Do you know of any keyboard shortcut that requires the `Esc` key to be hit twice in a row?  Do you have any further insight to this scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the scene, there are two windows open (Mozilla in background, and what looks like Xemacs in foreground, along with a KDE 3 taskbar at the bottom). Later each keypress makes one window disappear together with its taskbar button.

It's probably a dramatization, but it's not too far off actually pressing Alt+F4 twice.

> assuming it's a legitimate keyboard shortcut at all

The thing about keyboard shortcuts is that *you can make your own* – no such thing as "not a legitimate keyboard shortcut", especially on a Linux/X11 system. There is no way to know whether a completely stock KDE 3 is depicted, or whether there have been any customizations lab-wide or under someone's personal account.

Comment: Maybe he was just binge watching cat videos on YouTube and just wanted to exit out of full screen.